# Draw on image for marking particular object and save to photo library

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, drawing

I am new to swift. I am working on project in which my requirement is that I want to select image from photo library or take photo from camera and after selecting image I want to draw on that image for highlighting some part of image.

I searched a lot and I found some links which I am sharing with you in those link there are too many extra things so I am not able to understand how to take only image draw functionality from that project:

[https://github.com/eventtus/photo-editor]

I did't able to try because I this project there are too many things

So if anyone have simple demo app or reference link  or any other solutions for the same then please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load an Image from the photo library, you can do this:

```
func openSelectImage(type: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(type) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = type
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Just call this method and the Image Picker will appear. Of course you have to conform to the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`. So you do something like this:

```
extension MyAwesomeViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {          
            // do something with the image
            self.imageView.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

Now you are able to load an image into an ImageView or something.
Now the part with the drawing. I think that is way too much stuff for you as you should learn the basics first. But if you are interested in learning it, here you go:

- [Swift 3.0 - Drawing on imageView with finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108417/swift-3-0-drawing-on-imageview-with-finger)
- [Swift - Using CGContext to draw with finger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221814/swift-using-cgcontext-to-draw-with-finger)

I hope that leads you into the right direction!

Happy Coding!

Comment: yes thanks i will try this and thank you for helping me

Comment: If this helped you, I would be happy if you mark the answer as solved.